# Meaning of caret (^) in a Regular Expression

Tags: regex

If I search `^W` on http://regexr.com/ then it selects the first character `W` of the whole document. Now if I search `^E` then it doesn't select `E` of `Edit` word of the next line.

So, does caret (^) anchor match the start of line or whole document in regex?

Comment: Regexr.com only supports JS regex flavor. Use `/m` flag to allow `^` to match the start of a line. If you are using Ruby, the `^` always matches the start of a line.

Comment: Test on https://regex101.com

Comment: @xenteros I tried on regex101 too it gives same result.

Comment: Note _carrot_ is [another thing](https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/Carrot1.jpg). _^_ is a _caret_.

Comment: Both. [It depends](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/452/anchor-characters-caret#t=201609091058364057881).

Comment: Regex101 does not support Ruby regex flavor, try at Rubular.com. See the linked answer: *`^` represents the **start of the current line in multi-line mode**, otherwise the start of the string*

Comment: Interesting, we cannot use SO Documenation pages to close questions with.

Comment: I did not know regex is dealt differently in different languages.